# How to add HTML Tags along with a Java String?

Tags: java, html, string, tags

I have a java `String` which I need to appear in a mail body. After this message, I want to add a HTML button. How can I do this?

My string:

```
String customerMessage = "Hi, We have received your request. Your account will be unblocked within 48 hours.
```

What I want to add is after 2 lines breaks:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_parent">
  <button>Click me !</button>
</a>
```

Comment: which framework use to development ....?

Comment: You have to write the HTML code as a `String`... If you want to have linebreaks in HTML, then add `"<br>"` at the end of the HTML-Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the HTML code as a String and add `<br>` in string for break. Like :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hi, We have received your request. Your account will be unblocked within 48 hours.");
sb.append("<br><br><a href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\"><button>Click me !</button></a>");
```